# Is the zero polynomial a monomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I was inspired to ask this question after reading a precalculus textbook. In that book, there was a definition of a monomial as being a polynomial with only one term. So, for example, working over the complex numbers, $ix^2$, $2x^5$, and $4$ are all monomials. I decided to formalize this definition and make it more rigorous by defining a monomial as a polynomial such that all the coefficients except one are zero. But that raises the question, what about the zero polynomial? Should it be a monomial, or not? To put it another way, should the definition of monomial be as I stated it, or should it be "a polynomial such that all the coefficients **except possibly** one are zero"?

Comment: I would just say "at most one coefficient is nonzero," if it eases you any. But I think if we're going to get this nitpicky into the definition, we need to formally define the zero polynomial too. What are its coefficients? *Can* it have coefficients? Are we viewing constant polynomials $f(x) = c$ as simply being $f(x) = c \cdot x^0 = c \cdot 1$? If so, I think the "at most one" definition works fine.

Comment: I don't recommend blind acceptance of Wikipedia entries on mathematics, but they define "monomial" in a way that excludes the zero polynomial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial.

Comment: Notwithstanding what Wikipedia says, however, there is apparently some inconsistency about how the work *monomial* is used by different writers; see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Monomial.html. In the end, the distinctions between the competing definitions, and the question of whether $0$ is a monomial, may not really matter. In what context do you intend to use the word "monomial" where it will be a problem if $0$ is not a monomial?

Comment: @TedShifrin  $3x = 0x^5+3x+0.$